NestJs/Bull, runs fine locally but does not work in the cloud
I'm facing an issue with implementing a Bull queue in my NestJS application. I'm using PM2 to manage the application and NGINX as a reverse proxy. The job IDs are stored in Redis, but for some reason, everything just stops and the Bull queue doesn't process the jobs as expected.
I've tried the following:
Using both local Redis and cloud Redis (e.g., Redis Cloud).
Verified that Redis is running and accessible.
Ensured that my Bull queues are correctly initialized in NestJS.
Restarting the app with PM2.
However, the issue persists, and jobs in the queue don't seem to get processed consistently. Any ideas or suggestions on what might be causing this?
Tech Stack:

NestJS (using @nestjs/bull)
Bull (v4.x)
PM2 (for process management)
NGINX (for reverse proxy)
Redis (both local and Redis Cloud)

Additional Info:

Redis connection is established successfully.
Jobs get queued but are not processed.
Everything stops after a while, and Bull doesn't seem to be running well.
Thank you for your help!


